# When to use bash ANSI C style escape, e.g. $'\n'

Tags: quoting, escape-characters, newlines

I don't use bash often but I recall in the past to pass a tab or newline on the command line I would have to escape the character using the special `$` character before a single quoted string. Like `$'\t'`, `$'\n'`, etc. I had read about [quotes and escaping in the bash manual.](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings)

What I want to know is when it's appropriate to use an ANSI C style escape. For example I was working with a regex in grep and it appeared I needed an ANSI C style escape for a newline. Then I switched to perl and it seemed I didn't.

Take for example [my recent question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794759/perl-binary-stdin-multiline-regex) about a perl regex that didn't work. Here's the regex I was using:

```
echo -e -n "ab\r\ncd" | perl -w -e $'binmode STDIN;undef $/;$_ = <>;if(/ab\r\ncd/){print "test"}'
```

It turns out that is actually incorrect because I gave the string ANSI C style escape by using `$`. I just don't understand when I'm supposed to prepend the dollar sign and when I'm not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `$'...'` when you want escape sequences to be interpreted by the shell.

```
$ echo 'a\nb'
a\nb

$ echo $'a\nb'
a
b
```

In `perl`, `-e` option get a string. If you use `$'...'`, the escape sequences in string are interpreted before passing to `perl`. In your case, `\r` had gone and never passed to `perl`.

With `$'...'`:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -we $'binmode STDIN;undef $/;$_ = <>;if(/ab\r\ncd/){print "test"}'
BEGIN { $^W = 1; }
binmode STDIN;
undef $/;
$_ = <ARGV>;
if (/ab\ncd/) {
    print 'test';
}
-e syntax OK
```

Without it:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -we 'binmode STDIN;undef $/;$_ = <>;if(/ab\r\ncd/){print "test"}'
BEGIN { $^W = 1; }
binmode STDIN;
undef $/;
$_ = <ARGV>;
if (/ab\r\ncd/) {
    print 'test';
}
-e syntax OK
```

Comment: I don't understand. Where did the `\r` go and why?

Comment: @test: Because `perl` convert `\n` and your OS's native newline, see: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html

Comment: Well it is hard to understand you but I think what you mean is `\r\n` is converted to `\n` by perl. I read that webpage but it only says the conversion is "reading from or writing to text files." However I assume that because perl receives the \r\n as an actual carriage return and linefeed when using `$`, and not literally the characters backslash-r-backslash-n as when not using `$`, that it converts that to the linefeed character which is literally backslash-n.

Comment: @test: $'\r\n' produces a newline. `perl` read input, it saw a newline, and since when you're in Linux, perl represent a newline with '\n'. When you used '\r\n', `perl` saw them as a escape sequence literal.

Answer (score 2):

`$'\n'` is basically the same as typing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

So in your Perl example, it turns into*

```
  if(/ab
cd/)
```

Which isn't what you wanted.

Reasons I can think of to use `$'...'`:

- You want to put a single quote inside a single-quote delimited string, e.g. `logger $'Can\'t open file'`
- To make non-printable characters clearer, e.g. `$'a\tb'` rather than `'a<TAB character>b'`

(Not sure if `\r\n` is treated as equivalent to `\n` or if Perl sees carriage return + newline, but in either case, it's not it what you wanted.)

Comment: use $'\r\n', `perl` only see a newline, and will represent it as '\n'.

Comment: Another reason: when I use `youtube-dl` I sometimes get video files with newlines in them and removing them is a nightmare without `$'\n'`